# Empty tags returns Null Exception while Parsing Xml in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, tags, xml-parsing

I'm having some problems while parsing Xml in blackberry.
If the Xml contains empty tag .
the code returns  a Null exception..
Some solutions suggest to use try and catch..What should i do to fix this problem????

and this is the parsing code

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory= DocumentBuilderFactory. newInstance(); 
             DocumentBuilder docBuilder= docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
             docBuilder.isValidating();
             doc = docBuilder.parse(conn.openInputStream());

             doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
             list=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
             node=new String();
             element = new String();

             //this "for" loop is used to extract all elements and their value, so they can be displayed on the device

             for (int i=0;i<list.getLength();i++){
                 Node value=list.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0);
                 //getting attribute ==> Node value=list.item(i).getAttributes().item(0);


                 node=list.item(i).getNodeName();
                 element=value.getNodeValue();
                 if(node.equals("Name")){
                 //  some code goes here
```

The empty Tags such as:  < / tags  > 
or  < tag > < tag / >

Answer (score 0):

Which part of your code is throwing the null pointer exception? Your code appears to assume all results returned by getElementsByTagName will have children nodes, which is problematic, since the query is for all nodes in the document.

Answer (score 0):

// Text is your tag name.

```
NodeList _textNdList = doc.getElementsByTagName(Text);  

String result = getXMLTagValue(_textNdList,0);

public static String getXMLTagValue(NodeList node,int id)
    {
        if(node.item(id).getChildNodes().item(0) == null)
            return "";
        else
            return node.item(id).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
    }
```

It will help you. I was also facing the same issue. And, i did resolve that using this.`

---

`